# sequelize and sequelize-hierarchy: How do I execute an accessor in a model getter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using `sequelize` and `sequelize-hierarchy` in my app, and have partially defined a model like:

```
ancestors : {
    type: orm.Sequelize.VIRTUAL,
    get: function() { return 'TODO how return getAncestors here?' }
  }
```

Inside the getter, how can I access the `getAncestors()` method provided by `sequelize-hierarchy`?

Comment: Please answer your own question and mark it as accepted since you already have an answer from the `sequelize-hierarchy` developer here https://github.com/overlookmotel/sequelize-hierarchy/issues/20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@leroydev Thanks for the recordatory ;)

As the developer said to me in the issue:

> I'm afraid this isn't possible. You'd need to load the ancestors first
>   with include. A getter can't execute asynchronously, and therefore
>   can't fetch the ancestors from the database. When you use include, it
>   fetches them at the same time as the main query.
>
> This is a limitation of Sequelize (actually I think quite a reasonable
>   one). I'm afraid there's nothing I can do about it, so am closing this
>   PR.

Reference: https://github.com/overlookmotel/sequelize-hierarchy/issues/20